# Protocol that has method return type View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to achieve some polymorphism in building views in swiftui:

Something like this:

```
protocol Builder {
    func viewForItem() -> View
}

extension ItemPhoto: Builder {
    public func viewForItem() -> View {
        Image("image.png")
    }
}
```

I receive error:

```
Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

If I try to use `associatedtype` I have following problem

```
protocol Builder {
    associatedtype T
    func viewForItem() -> T
}


extension ItemPhoto: Builder {
    typealias T = Image

    public func viewForItem() -> Image {
        Image("image.png").scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

If I want to do any view building I receive error

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'Image'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution.

#### Update: Xcode 13.4 - now I would propose

```
protocol Builder {
    associatedtype T: View
    @ViewBuilder func buildView() -> T
}
```

#### Original: Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
protocol Builder {
    associatedtype T:View    // << not exact, but just a View !!
    func viewForItem() -> T
}

struct ItemPhoto { // << just for testing
}

extension ItemPhoto: Builder {

    public func viewForItem() -> some View { // opaque !!
        Image("image.png").scaledToFit()
    }
}
```